# How to access application default credentials from a GCE container without any Google API binding?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am writing an application that runs in a container, on Google Container Engine, in a language that doesn't have any binding to the Google API.

I need to access the application default credentials. Unfortunately the official documentation doesn't explain how to do such a thing in production environment without using one of the existing bindings to the Google API.

In development environment (i.e. on my local dev machine) I export the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable, but it isn't available in the production container. Does it mean I have to use some endpoint from the REST API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby's implementation is open source and can be accessed [here](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby).

### Different locations to check by priority

The [`get_application_default`](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/master/lib/googleauth.rb#L114-L121) method clearly shows that:

1. the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable is checked,
2. then the PATH is checked,
3. then the default path `/etc/google/auth` is checked,
4. finally, if still nothing and on a compute instance, a new access token is fetched.

```ruby
def get_application_default(scope = nil, options = {})
  creds = DefaultCredentials.from_env(scope) ||
          DefaultCredentials.from_well_known_path(scope) ||
          DefaultCredentials.from_system_default_path(scope)
  return creds unless creds.nil?
  raise NOT_FOUND_ERROR unless GCECredentials.on_gce?(options)
  GCECredentials.new
end
```

It is consistent with what says [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials):

> 1. The environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is checked. If
>      this variable is specified it should point to a file that defines the
>      credentials. [...]
> 2. If you have installed the Google Cloud SDK on your machine and have run
>      the command gcloud auth application-default login, your identity can
>      be used as a proxy to test code calling APIs from that machine.
> 3. If you
>      are running in Google App Engine production, the built-in service
>      account associated with the application will be used.
> 4. If you are running in Google Compute Engine production, the built-in service
>      account associated with the virtual machine instance will be used.
> 5. If none of these conditions is true, an error will occur.

### Detecting GCE environment

The [`on_gce?`](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/37ed189b2e5165243918fcde127ebe323e9a06b5/lib/googleauth/compute_engine.rb#L63-L81) method shows how to check whether we are on GCE by sending a GET/HEAD HTTP request to http://169.254.169.254. If there is a `Metadata-Flavor: Google` header in the response, then it's probably GCE.

```ruby
def on_gce?(options = {})
  c = options[:connection] || Faraday.default_connection
  resp = c.get(COMPUTE_CHECK_URI) do |req|
    # Comment from: oauth2client/client.py
    #
    # Note: the explicit `timeout` below is a workaround. The underlying
    # issue is that resolving an unknown host on some networks will take
    # 20-30 seconds; making this timeout short fixes the issue, but
    # could lead to false negatives in the event that we are on GCE, but
    # the metadata resolution was particularly slow. The latter case is
    # "unlikely".
    req.options.timeout = 0.1
  end
  return false unless resp.status == 200
  return false unless resp.headers.key?('Metadata-Flavor')
  return resp.headers['Metadata-Flavor'] == 'Google'
rescue Faraday::TimeoutError, Faraday::ConnectionFailed
  return false
end
```

### Fetching an access token directly from Google

If the default credentials could not be found on the filesystem and the application is running on GCE, we can ask a new access token without any prior authentication. This is possible because of the default service account, that is created automatically when GCE is enabled in a project.

The [`fetch_access_token`](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby/blob/37ed189b2e5165243918fcde127ebe323e9a06b5/lib/googleauth/compute_engine.rb#L88-L101) method shows how, from a GCE instance, we can get a new access token by simply issuing a GET request to `http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token`.

```ruby
def fetch_access_token(options = {})
  c = options[:connection] || Faraday.default_connection
  c.headers = { 'Metadata-Flavor' => 'Google' }
  resp = c.get(COMPUTE_AUTH_TOKEN_URI)
  case resp.status
  when 200
    Signet::OAuth2.parse_credentials(resp.body,
                                     resp.headers['content-type'])
  when 404
    raise(Signet::AuthorizationError, NO_METADATA_SERVER_ERROR)
  else
    msg = "Unexpected error code #{resp.status}" + UNEXPECTED_ERROR_SUFFIX
    raise(Signet::AuthorizationError, msg)
  end
end
```

Here is a curl command to illustrate:

```
curl \
  http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google'
```